# How do i prove that a dilation(?) of a Borel set is a Borel set?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Define $\mathbb{R}^+ \cdot A = \{rb\in\mathbb{R}^n:r\in (0,\infty) , b\in A\}$, $\forall A\subset \mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$

Let $\mathscr{B}$ denotes the Borel-algebra.

Let $A\in\mathscr{B}_{\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}}$

How do i prove that $\mathbb{R}^+\cdot A\in\mathscr{B}_{\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}}$?

*Below is what i have proven:

> Let $S^{n-1}$ be a unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$
>
> Then, $\forall A\in\mathscr{B}_{S^{n-1}}, \mathbb{R}^+\cdot A\in\mathscr{B}_{\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}}$

I'm not sure whether this result helps you to explain how to prove the question I'm asking here in this post though..

Thank you in advance.. Please help me

Comment: Prove that the dilation of an open ball is an open ball, the complement of a dilation is a dilation of the complement, etc.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo For a fixed radius $r$, your comment is clear to me, but here $r$ is not a fixed value, it is rather an arbitrary element in $(0,\infty)$. I'm not really clear.. Could you be more explicit? Thank you sir

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Moreover, I have also proven that "For any open set $V$ in $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$, $\mathbb{R}^+\cdot V$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus\{0\}$." I don't know how this could be used to prove the question i asked in my post..

Comment: I see what the source of confusion is. Can you prove that each set in the collection you have is a Borel set?

Comment: @AndresCaicedo I'm sorry, but which *collection* are you referring to? Would you please check amudhan's answer below and my comments on that answer? That was what exactly i tried to do and what exactly i'm having a trouble with..

Answer (score 0):

Use the usual sigma-algebra trick. Show that the set 
$ \{ A \in \mathscr{B}_{\mathbb{R}^n \setminus 0} | \mathbb{R}^+ \cdot A \in \mathscr{B}_{\mathbb{R}^n\setminus 0 } \}$ is a sigma-algebra.

Then, since the open sets are contained in this sigma-algebra, it has to be the entire Borel set.

Comment: This is exactly what i tried. I have a problem with showing the given set in your answer is indeed a sigma-algebra.. How is it a sigma-algebra?

Comment: Imagine a Borel-set $A$ which contains infinitely many rays $y=cx, (x\in(0,\infty))$, such that $\mathbb{R}^+\cdot A$ is a Borel set. How could you assure that $\mathbb{R}^+ \cdot A^c$ is a Borel-set? Note that $\mathbb{R}^+ \cdot A$ and $\mathbb{R}^+\cdot A^c$ may *not* be disjoint